# ant script throwing an exception while calculating md5

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

HI I am using ant script to calcalte md5 of two files in a particular folder.This the is the script which i have written

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Hello World Project" basedir="." default="info">
    <property name="cms.dir" value="D:\CMS\webclient\components\CMS\Address\AddressSearch" />
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
    <target name="info">
        <echo>Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!</echo>
        <fileset id="src.files" dir="${cms.dir}" casesensitive="yes">
            <include name="**/*.uim"/>
            <include name="**/*.properties"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}" property="sounds" refid="src.files">
        </pathconvert>
        <echo file="sounds.txt">${sounds}</echo>
        <loadfile property="files" srcFile="./sounds.txt"/>
        <for list="${files}" delimiter="," param="file1">
            <sequential>
                <echo>@{file1}</echo>
                <checksum file="@{file1}" todir="./checksum" />
            </sequential>
        </for>
    </target>
</project>
```

The file name is getting printed correctly but when i am using the same file to calculate the md5 it is throwing an exception like this

```
BUILD FAILED
    C:\build.xml:15: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    C:\build.xml:18: Could not find file D:\CMS\webclient\components\CMS\Address\Add
    ressSearch\CMS_addressSearchPopUp.properties
    D:\CMS\webclient\components\CMS\Address\AddressSearch\CMS_addressSearchPopUp.uim
    to generate checksum for.
```

any help regarding this

Comment: Which file are you trying to md5sum? That error message makes it look like it couldn't find a file called "`D:\CMS\webclient\components\CMS\Address\AddressSearch\CMS_addressSearchPopUp.properties` + `\n` + `D:\CMS\webclient\components\CMS\Address\AddressSearch\CMS_addressSearchPopUp.uim`"

Comment: I am placing the checksum in a for loop so i need to calculate the md5 for both the files

Comment: Based on that error, it doesn't look like your string is being separated as you're intending. Is `sounds.txt` actually comma-delimited, or does that file have one filename per line (ie, newline-delimited)?

Answer (score 0):

You are using  new line when creating "sounds", but is using  comma to split.

```
<pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}" property="sounds" refid="src.files">
```

Then this is written to a file - *sounds.txt*

Then reads the file, to split using comma. (","

```
<for list="${files}" delimiter="," param="file1">
```

If I understood the question correctly, you should split using new line

```
   <for list="${files}" delimiter="${line.separator}" param="file1">
```